# Sierra Automator KeyboardViewer App Shortcut

Tags: keyboard, macos, applescript, automator, shortcut

KeyboardViewer app is saved from this AppleScript.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    if application "KeyboardViewer" is running then
        quit application "KeyboardViewer"
    else 
        activate application "KeyboardViewer"
    end if
    return input
end run
```

Dock toggle save. Adding shortcut to above, needs some work...

**Syntax error** Can’t set application "KeyboardViewer" to some object. Access not allowed.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set application "KeyboardViewer" to (keystroke "K" using control down)
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all! `process whose frontmost is true and visible is true` froze Keyboard Viewer behind a Finder window that also froze - 2 freezes in 2 days. Following seems to work quite well, in macOS 10.13.2. Simply add the `delay 1`.

```
    on run {input, parameters}
        if application "KeyboardViewer" is running then
            quit application "KeyboardViewer"
            delay 1
        else if application "KeyboardViewer" is not running then
            activate application "KeyboardViewer"
        end if
        return input
    end run
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to assign a *keyboard shortcut* to an **AppleScript** *application*, you'll need to do it as an **Automator Service**. However, one of the issues you'll run into, when **Keyboard Viewer** has focus is, it will eat the *keyboard shortcut* and not close **Keyboard Viewer**. You'd have to set focus away from **Keyboard Viewer** in order for the **Automator Service** to close **Keyboard Viewer**.

The following **AppleScript** *code* does that, providing you have not set focus to it after it opens or reset it elsewhere if you did.

```
on run
    tell application "System Events"
        set activeApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true and visible is true
    end tell
    if application "KeyboardViewer" is running then
        quit application "KeyboardViewer"
    else
        activate application "KeyboardViewer"
    end if
    tell application activeApp to activate
end run
```

In **Automator** create a new **Service** *workflow* with the following setting:

- **Service receives no input in any application**
- *Add* a **Run AppleScript** *action*.

  - *Replace* the default *code* with the *code* above.
  - *Click* the **Compile** button (Hammer icon).
- *Save* it as e.g.: **Toggle Keyboard Viewer**
- In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Services** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

  - *Find* e.g. **Toggle Keyboard Viewer** and give it a *shortcut*.
  - I gave it: **⌥⌘K**

**Note:** Finding a *keyboard shortcut* that isn't already taken by another app can be a challenge. In this use case, any application that has focus when e.g. **⌥⌘K** is pressed, it will go to the app's assigned *command* before it goes to the e.g.: **Toggle Keyboard Viewer** service. You might need to go to a four key *keyboard shortcut*, e.g.: **^⌥⌘K**

[image: Automator Service]

[image: System Preferences > Keyboard > Services > Shortcuts** > Services]

Comment: I did try Services approach, but shortcut was ignored. Then tried same application-and-services approaches, using launchd keyboardservicesd, same result. Perhaps an if-else, but then if-else cannot handle keystroke assignment (syntax good but system cannot parse). Nulaana Shortcuts FAQ https://www.nulana.com/support/ - tell application "System Events" 
delay 0.5
keystroke "n" using {command down, control down} end tell

Comment: Nulana's Delay 0.5 works, keystroke seated in Dock's toggle icon application but... Now we have problem KeyboardViewer is open, and app just highlights shortcut keys, intercepting and cutting off any application-services shortcut settings. I think this effort needs to inject something more into launchd. Btw, instructions above very well done.

Comment: @mark stewart, What I posted works, I would not have posted it otherwise! Saying "I did try Services approach, but shortcut was ignored." is on no value without knowing what keyboard shortcut you assigned. Did you read my **Note:** in my answer? If the keyboard shortcut you assigned was done by the code you show in the OP, i.e. `tell application "System Events" set application "KeyboardViewer" to (keystroke "K" using control down)` You cannot assign a keyboard shortcut in that manned, it's improper coding regardless of the fact that it compiles. Read the first part of my answer up to the code.

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste what works for you, not working here, just an error beep. Put this to Nulana support, as sending new mail with other apps open blocks Nulana too. Nulana opens my old Lion Gem, but sometimes close just displays keypress. Launchd (500), for Sierra 10.12.6. Wonder what happens to keyboardservicesd in High Sierra? Flakey applet. Maybe certain Accessibility features make KeyboardViewer.app more stable? Feedback to Apple, requesting more robust app... Got to be careful here, new mp6,1 may be replaced soon.

Comment: user3439894 wrote: "is on no value without knowing what keyboard shortcut you assigned"

Comment: user3439894 ... I followed your post, not working here. Nulana Shortcuts.app does work without too many apps running. Maybe ELSE could be used to make your version an IF against my sweet and simple. So IF my version does not close THEN your version would. Nice thing about just using a Dock shortcut to my Automator KeyView.app is that in Keyboard preferences any shortcut used may interfere less with Mac global shortcuts.