# How to launch the onscreen Accessibility Keyboard with a keyboard shortcut too?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, accessibility

With <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>, macOS launches Emojis & Symbols, also know as the Character Viewer.

Is there a shortcut to launch the Keyboard Viewer?

Comment: Have a look at my answer: [RE: Sierra Automator KeyboardViewer App Shortcut](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303406/sierra-automator-keyboardviewer-app-shortcut/303410#303410)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to use a keyboard shortcut to display or hide the accessibility keyboard.

I'm understanding your question to only be about showing & hiding the accessibility keyboard with a keyboard shortcut and not about how to use that keyboard or any other accessibility feature.  If that's not correct, please edit your question or add a comment to clarify.

One-sentence answers are usually not very good but in this case there's not much more to add that would improve the answer.

Comment: Yes, i'm looking for a way to launch/display the onscreen keyboard using a keyboard shortcut. I need to write in 3 different languages and i sometimes need it to be on the screen to help me locate some characters and type them on the physical keyboard. A shortcut would be much better/faster/easier than each time going to the flag icon and clicking on the 'show the onscreen keyboard viewer' menu